# proxy_pass priority and location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to proxy all incoming requests from nginx to NodeJS, excluding uri "/cabinet/...". So according to official nginx documentation, it's work perfectly when I am trying to proceed file on same server, but when I am trying proxy to node server, whole request are forced to node (including /cabinet/)

So what I am doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.dev;
    root "/home/vagrant/code/cabinet/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /cabinet/ {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index2.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.dev-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.dev.key;
}
```

Comment: The order is correct. The issue may be something else. Can you check in a incognito window? Also make sure nothing else is wrong, check the nginx logs

Comment: Thanks for reply, nginx logs is empty because all requests are proxied to node server, incognito mode is not helps too.

Comment: Location `/cabinet/` redirects to `/index2.html` which then goes through the proxy. Did you mean `/cabinet/index2.html`?

Comment: No, /cabinet/index2.html must relate to local server, but currently it goes to proxy node js server, that is the issue.